# Flux query multiply one measure by a number

Tags: influxdb-2, influxql

In SQL this would be easy:

```
SELECT batt_level, generation/3000 FROM Wherever
```

But is this possible in Flux?
The closest I've got is:

```
from(bucket: "solar")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "batt_level" or r["_measurement"] == "generation")
  |> map(fn: (r) => {r with _value = if r["_measurement"] == "generation" then r._value / 3000 else r._value})
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

but it doesn't work. It says

```
 error @4:29-4:109: missing return statement in block error @4:24-4:28: undefined identifier with
```

whih is infuriating because I copied that `with` thing from https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/mathematic-operations/
Is the documentation wrong?

It also seems really cumbersome having to use the `if` to select the colum you want to use; is this normal for Flux of does it have some other way of doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

It indeed seems like a bug in the documentation.
The correct syntax for `if` use with *with* in `map` is like this:

```js
from(bucket: "solar")
  |> ...
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _value: if r["_measurement"] == "generation" then r._value / 3000 else r._value}))
  |> ...
```